# Why do I get this error everytime when import importing numba

Tags: python, numba

whenever I import numba I get this error.
sorry if title is kind of random but stackoverflow forced me to write a longer one
`OSError: Could not find/load shared object file: llvmlite.dll Error was: Could not find module 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\llvmlite\binding\llvmlite.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.`

I've tried installing llvmlite with anaconda and also installing numba with anaconda and all sorts of things but the error isn't going away

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Numba does not succeed to find the library file (LLVM-Lite is the JIT-compiler of Numba based on the LLVM toolchain), but does the target file actually exists? If so, what about adding it in the PATH environment variable? If this is still not working, then you can try to reinstall the module using standard tools. If this is still not working, then you can try the embedded Python version and provide information so we can reproduce the problem on our machine or understand what is going wrong.